# Algebra over non-commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

(All rings and homomorphisms assumed unital) Let $K$ be a commutative ring. A $K$-algebra is a pair $(R,\phi)$ where $R$ is a ring and $\phi:K\rightarrow Z(R)$ is a ring homomorphism.

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $R$ is trivially an $R$-algebra. I am intrerested in an extension of this concept to non-commutative rings.

**Are there any results regarding the existence of ring homomorphisms $R\rightarrow Z(R)$ when $R$ is non-commutative?** Or are these things even useful?

I believe have been successful in constructing an example (though may have made a mistake as I'm very tired). Let $R$ be the ring ${\rm End}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. Denote its elements $z,i,g,h$ which act on $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as follows

$$i([a])=[a], \quad z([a])=[0]\quad g([a])=[1], \quad h([a])=[a+1]\quad  \forall a\in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \quad$$
Then define $\phi:R\rightarrow Z(R)$ by 
$$\phi(z)=z, \quad \phi(i)=i, \quad \phi(g)=z, \quad \phi(h)=i$$

Comment: Maybe this can give an insight https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21899/definition-of-an-algebra-over-a-noncommutative-ring

Comment: @JJR Thank you, that was interesting.